# PEWC (prior express written consent) legal copy. Font size

Tags: accessibility, legal

I am working with cross-channel teams to develop a modal that has PEWC (prior express written consent) legal copy added to the form. Does anyone know if there are font restrictions on displaying that legal text? As in does it need to be a certain font size? What about placement? Any feedback would be great.

I have tried putting the text next to the main CTA on the page in 10px caption text. But the attorney said that it has to be bigger.

Comment: I have never heard of PEWC, so can not comment. But I suspect it must be the same WCAG rules, since they are used by all countries with disability laws.

Answer (score 1):

It is an interesting question to ask because most of the time it seems like people are trying to make the so called 'fine print' as small and difficult to read as possible.

As far as the font is concerned, there are definitely no standards that I know of that exists. There are branding or writing style guidelines to be followed, and they may specify certain aspects of the font size or legibility requirements to be met.

Outside of that, it is important to recognize the relationship between the size of the font, the style of the font and the legibility of the text. There are also additional factors like the line spacing, page width and contrast to the normal body text to consider.

Hopefully this gives you some idea about some of the design elements that go into text that is displayed to the reader.